# How to create a common function in codeigniter for checking if session exist?

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, session

I am creating an application where in users have to login to access various modules. I need to check if the user session exist before providing access to each module.

Now I am checking session like this in each function / module / controller to avoid unauthorized access.

```
if($this->session->userdata('userId')!=''){
   do something;  }
```

Is there a better way to do this? can I have common function similar like

```
sessionExist();
```

such that it can be called from any module / controller / function which is common to the whole project?

If so where should I write this common function such that it can be called from anywhere.

Comment: if you have classes where every method requires login - then you can put a log in check in the constructor. much cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a helper function, here it is:

```
if ( ! function_exists('sessionExist'))
{
    function sessionExist(){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return (bool) $CI->session->userdata('userId');
    }
}
```

Save the file in `application/helpers/` and include it your `application/config/autoload.php` file:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('my_helper_file');
```

Answer (score 6):

If it's class, then create [library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html). if only function then create [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html), and then [autoload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) them so it can be called anywhare.

Comment: I agree with your idea! +1 From me!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in library that you created it or another library

ex: `application/libraries/Common.php`

```
public function logged_in()
{    
   return (bool) $this->session->userdata('userId');
}
```

Using like this:

```
if ($this->common->logged_in()) {
   // User logged
} else {
   // User not logged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model where you set your session:

```
   $data = array(
      'sid' =>$this->input->post('sid'),
       'is_logged_in' => true,
      );
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

And in your function / module / controller:

```
    function __construct(){
    $this->is_logged_in()
    }

   function is_logged_in(){
    $is_logged_in =$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

    if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != TRUE)
    {
        echo 'You dont have permission to acces this page';
        die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! function_exists('sessionExist'))
 
{ 

   function sessionExist(){

         $CI =& get_instance(); 

         $userId = $CI->session->userdata('userId');

         if(empty($userId)){ 

          redirect(base_url('login'));
 
         }else{ 

           return (bool)$userId;

         }

    }

}
```